# Regarding DeSmuME - Where are my 'file', 'view', 'config', etc.?

Tags: software-installation

Just recently installed desmume via software-center on the latest Ubuntu install (16.04.1).  ROMs can be executed with the software and run smoothly.  However, there are no options for saving game states, configuring, changing volume, etc.  Anyone have an idea as to why I am missing these options?  All posts and tuts of using the program have these settings included.  I removed and reinstalled due to lack of better ideas.  Any help is much appreciated.

[image: This is what I am looking at]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu bars in Ubuntu are at the top panel when a program is opened, even though it is not full screen just move the mouse to the top panel and the menus for Desmume will be revealed.

However, I had some bad luck with Desmume on Ubuntu 16.04 as I am unable to access any category in the menus above, and only those which are accessible by a keyboard shortcut was I able to open.

Comment: Ditto.  All categories are unresponsive.  If you find a solution to the problem, let me know!